# ¿Qué significa "gentrificación"?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, significado, neologismos

El otro día usaron en una película el término *gentrificación*. No recuerdo la frase exacta pero era algo así como:

> Yo pensaba que este barrio ya habría empezado un proceso de gentrificación.

No era la primera vez que oía esa palabra, pero fui incapaz de inferir su significado por el contexto, aunque entiendo que es un neologismo adaptado del inglés *gentrification*.

Así pues, ¿qué es exactamente una *gentrificación*? ¿Existe alguna alternativa a la adaptación tal cual de la voz inglesa?

Comment: No tengo propuesta concreta, pero quería agregar que en inglés ese término incluye una actitud crítica.  Imagina una conversación entre dos residentes de hace tiempo del barrio que empieza a sufrir cambios, al ver pasar a un recién llegado en su coche de último modelo.  El uno dice al otro algo de la "gentrification" -- no solo se refiere al proceso que describiste en tu respuesta, sino también una valoración negativa de los recien llegados, que son conspicuos en su consumo de bienes caros, y que tienen cierta actitud, de menospreciar a los que estaban ahí desde antes.  Es ...

Comment: ... decir, "gentrification" también dice algo del choque cultural.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La palabra *gentrificación* no está recogida en el DLE, pero se puede leer su significado en [la Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentrificaci%C3%B3n):

> El término **gentrificación** (proveniente del inglés *gentry*, «baja nobleza») se refiere al proceso de transformación de un espacio urbano deteriorado —o en declive— a partir de la preconstrucción —o rehabilitación edificatoria con mayores alturas que las existentes— que provoca un aumento de los alquileres o del coste habitacional en estos espacios. Esto induce a que los residentes tradicionales abandonen el barrio —y se afinquen en espacios más periféricos—, lo que produce que este «nuevo» espacio termine por ser ocupado por clases sociales con mayor capacidad económica que les permita afrontar estos nuevos costes.

Más escueta pero muy similar es la definición dada por [la Fundéu](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/gentrificacion/):

> *Gentrificación* es una adaptación adecuada al español del término inglés *gentrification*, con el que se alude al proceso mediante el cual la población original de un sector o barrio, generalmente céntrico y popular, es progresivamente desplazada por otra de un nivel adquisitivo mayor.

La Wikipedia aclara que *gentry* es "una clase social histórica inglesa de composición mixta entre la baja y media nobleza que viene a ser equivalente a la hidalguía española, y los propietarios de tierra plebeyos". Según Fundéu sería traducible como "alta burguesía, pequeña aristocracia, familia bien o gente de bien".

Existen algunas alternativas posibles:

> De las alternativas propuestas hasta ahora en español, ***elitización* o, más precisamente, *elitización residencial* es la que más se ajusta al sentido del término original**, frente a *aburguesamiento*, *recualificación social* o *aristocratización*, que no recogen los matices de este proceso.

Sin embargo, la propia Fundéu dice que es un "neologismo válido" en español. A pesar de que el término original inglés data de 1964, en español los primeros casos parecen ocurrir en estudios de geografía y urbanismo hacia finales de la década de 1970 según Ngram, y en prensa hacia finales de la década de 1980 según la hemeroteca de la BNE.

Resultan curiosas las definiciones de esos tratados de los 70 y principios de los 80:

> "Ocupación de las viviendas mejoradas por clases más ricas." (1979)
>   "Reinvasión del centro por clases acomodadas." (1981)

Como ejemplo de gentrificación se suele hablar del barrio de Chueca, en Madrid, como en este ejemplo de prensa que da la Fundéu:

> «Chueca es un ejemplo clásico de gentrificación: el barrio se ‘limpió’ en todos los sentidos, el tejido social cambió y se revalorizó el suelo.»

Comment: ¡Qué bueno! Me encanta la propuesta de _elitización_, encaja muchísimo con lo que se ve en los barrios céntricos de las grandes ciudades.

Comment: @fedorqui dada la definición de "gentry" que da la Wikipedia como correspondiente a "hidalguía", habría molado decir "hidalguización". :-D